# Allow update in FireStore in specific hours of every day

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to allow users to update their document only in specific hours say 19th hour in the evening to 5th hours in the next morning. I have found the way to compare between day but note the time. I need a way to compare the evening hours of the same day and the morning hours of the next day.

Answer (score 1):

This will make sure the update is only done between 19 and 5 **in UTC**:

```
allow update: if request.time.hours() > 19 && request.time.hours() < 5
```

You will have to customize this depending on the time zone you want to address